# Lemon Juice while workout

Tags: weight-loss, abdominals, post-workout

We are daily consuming 1 Lemon with 500ml of water as juice with sugar and salt, while workout we are taking a sip to stay hydrated.

- And whether it lose our weight or burn only fat? (mostly abdominal)
- Whether it's recommended to take daily?

We are taking whey protein as supplement after workout.

Comment: You're drinking lemonade basically, the sugar makes it high in calories so it won't help lose weight or burn fat but rather the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the two most prominent nutrients found in lemons that could play a role. These are vitamin C, and citric acid.

Lemons are rich in vitamin C. One fruit will deliver from 50% to 75% of the daily recommended amount, depending on the size of the lemon. That's nice, because it is an essential nutrient; humans can't synthesize it in their bodies. Now, does it promote fat loss? Doing a search yields a lot of articles that seem to state so, but many of them are from sources that I deem questionable at best. The source of this idea seems to stem from one study, conducted at the Arizona State University. Here is a link: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16945143

The study observes that fat oxidation was reduced in the test subjects who had a vitamin C **deficiency**. Note that this does not mean extra vitamin C is going to increase fat oxidation, it only concludes that there appears to be a correlation between vitamin C deficiency and slower fat loss. Articles reporting on such studies often make faulty leaps in logic. They think "if a shortage of something reduces fat loss, then a surplus it of will surely accelerate it!". Unscientific. However, you'll want to avoid a vitamin C deficiency and lemon juice is a good way to do it.

So then there's long-term effects. Although long-term consumption of excess vitamin C could be harmful, there's no reason to believe that one lemon each day on top of a regular diet comes anywhere close to such an excess. In fact, there's common foodstuffs much richer in vitamin C which you can eat frequently without any cause for concern.

Onto the citric acid. There is a metabolic pathway in your body called the "citric acid cycle" that plays a major role in the energy supply to tissues, not in the least your muscles. One of the metabolites needed in this cycle is citrate, a derivative of citric acid. So getting some extra from your food seems like a good idea.

Anything bad about citric acid? Dosages that are too large can cause side-effects, but again, one lemon is not going to get you even close to that amount. You'd probably have to take medicinal concentrations to be at risk. The only long-term effect I can think of is that frequent consumption could affect the tooth enamel. Since you're adding sugar and salt (creating a sort of homebrew isotonic drink) it could be comparable to some sodas, although I suspect your drink is less damaging to teeth than, say, a cola. If it worries you, perhaps use a straw, or avoid letting it wash over your teeth when taking a sip.

EDIT:
I'll add another consideration. Apart from the vitamin C and citric acid discussed above, lemons also contain specific polyphenols. Here is a study that investigates the effect of those polyphenols in modulating the weight gain **in mice** when provided with a diet that would **induce obesity**: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2581754/

The conclusion of the study is that a positive effect can be seen in reducing weight gain in the form of fat when supplementing the diet with these polyphenols. Since this is a study on rodents you can draw no hard conclusions on how it will affect humans, and it wouldn't prove that lemons would actually assist in weight **loss**, it only suggests they can have a positive effect in slowing weight gain.

So in summary:

- There is a lack of evidence that your drink will assist in fat **loss**.
- Current evidence suggests that the polyphenols in lemons can assist in reducing fat **gain**.

  - There is evidence that a lack in vitamin C will reduce fat oxidation. In this case the lemon drink would only help if you are otherwise deficient in vitamin C.
- There is no reason to suspect that drinking the juice of one lemon daily would have negative long-term effects.

This leaves us with the sugar and salt. If the sugar is not in excess of what your target for daily carbohydrate consumption is, and doesn't negate a caloric deficit, then it's fine. If the salt doesn't put you over the daily recommended allowance for your sodium intake, that too is not a problem.

I foresee no negative long-term effects but there isn't hard evidence that it will assist in fat burn. So it's a case of "if it doesn't help, at least it's not going to harm you".

Comment: `Overall, don't expect miracle results from your drink, but everything seems to point in the direction that it might be beneficial and won't harm you in the long term.` This is extremely vague. To the point that I don't know if you mean that it's simply good for overall health or if you expect it'll actually help OP burn fat (it wont).

Comment: @AlexL It **might** be beneficial and it **won't** be harmful in the long term. That's as accurate as it is going to get. I've given the reasons for both statements above. If I were to say outright "it's gonna do 0, zilch, nada for fat burn" I could be wrong, because the evidence I find suggests ONLY that a vitamin C deficit reduced fat burn. Lack of proof of something is not proof that it isn't true. If you've got a better answer supported by evidence, provide it.

Comment: That doesn't change that the last part of your answer is vague. The reason I say it won't help is the fact that the lemon juice is being combined with sugar.

Comment: I have edited the answer to consider the polyphenols in lemons and address the aspects of the sugar and salt.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment on the answer above, here are my remarks:

It won't be particularly helpful for weight loss, and it won't be particularly harmful for your body on the long term. Yet it **will be harmful** for your teeth.

So it's not a case of "there won't be any negative longterm effects", because there will be, for your teeth.